# Repeat Row between From and To Date Range

Tags: sql-server

Hi i am having leave table with From and To date column with no of days leave applied.I want to repeat the row between From and To date.

Actual Result

```
leaveid fromdate    Todate       noofdays
1       01/01/2019  02/01/2019      2
```

Excepted Result

```
  leveid  fromdate      Todate      
     1     01/01/2019   01/01/2019 
      2    02/01/2019    02/01/2019
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `master..[spt_values]` to generate the desired number of rows and use  `Dateadd` to generate the dates like following.

```
;with cte 
     as (select number 
         from   master..[spt_values] 
         where  type = 'p') 
select number+1 as leaveid, 
       Dateadd(day, number, fromdate) fromdate, 
       Dateadd(day, number, fromdate) todays 
from   @table t 
       inner join cte c 
               on c.number < t.noofdays
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/ZWK70801)

If you don't want to use `master..[spt_values]`, you can also use recursive `CTE` like following.

```
declare @maxNoOfDay int = (select max(noofdays) from @table)
;with seq( number ) as
(
    Select 0 as number
        union all
    Select number + 1
        from seq
        where number <= @maxNoOfDay
)

select number+1 as leaveid, 
       Dateadd(day, number, fromdate) fromdate, 
       Dateadd(day, number, fromdate) todays 
from   @table t 
       inner join seq c 
               on c.number < t.noofdays
```

**Output**

```
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| leaveid | fromdate                | todays                  |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1       | 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2       | 2019-01-02 00:00:00.000 | 2019-01-02 00:00:00.000 |
+---------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

**EDIT:**

If you want the dates in specific format, you can use `CONVERT` like following.

```
declare @maxNoOfDay int = (select max(noofdays) from @table)
;with seq( number ) as
(
    Select 0 as number
        union all
    Select number + 1
        from seq
        where number <= @maxNoOfDay
)

select number+1 as leaveid, 
       convert(varchar, Dateadd(day, number, fromdate), 103)  fromdate, 
       convert(varchar, Dateadd(day, number, fromdate), 103) todays 
from   @table t 
       inner join seq c 
               on c.number < t.noofdays
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/UTUR13530)

**Output**

```
+---------+------------+------------+
| leaveid | fromdate   | todays     |
+---------+------------+------------+
| 1       | 01/01/2019 | 01/01/2019 |
+---------+------------+------------+
| 2       | 02/01/2019 | 02/01/2019 |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: The second row `leaveid` should be 2 instead of 1

Comment: Good that you understand what I mean  :)